# Rails: build for difference between relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

A `doc` has many `articles` and *can* have many `edits`.

I want to build an `edit` for each `article` up to the total number of `@doc.articles`. This code works with the first build (i.e., when no `edits` yet exist).

```
def editing
  @doc = Doc.find(params[:id])
  unbuilt = @doc.articles - @doc.edits
  unbuilt.reverse.each do |article|
    @doc.edits.build(:body => article.body, :article_id => article.id, :doc_id => @doc.id)
  end
end
```

But when `edits` already exist it'll keep those `edits` and still build for the `@doc.articles` total, ending up with too many `edits` and some duplicates if only one `article` was changed.

I want to put some condition against `:article_id` which exists in both `edits` and `articles` in to say (in **pseudocode**):

```
unbuilt = @doc.articles - @doc.edits
unbuilt.where('article_id not in (?)', @doc.edits).reverse.each do |article|
  @doc.edits.build(...)
end
```

Any help would be excellent! Thank-you so much.

Comment: `build` has been used for only has_one relations you said that doc has_many edits so how can you use build for edits it should be `@doc.edits.create(..)` Thanks

Comment: `build` works fine in this case for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing something weird here:

```
unbuilt = @doc.articles - @doc.edits
```

You probably want this instead

```
unbuilt = @doc.articles - @doc.edits.map(&:article)
```

This works if @doc.articles and @doc.edits are small collections, otherwise a SQL solution would be preferred.

-- EDIT: added explanation --

this piece of Ruby

```
@doc.edits.map(&:article)
```

is equivalent to

```
@doc.edits.map do |edit| edit.article end
```

the previous one is much more compact and exploits a feature introduced in ruby 1.9

It basically takes a symbol (:article), calls on it the 'to_proc' method (it does this by using the '&' character). You can think of the 'to_proc' method as something very similar to this:

```
def to_proc
  proc { |object| object.send(self) }
end
```

In ruby, blocks and procs are generally equivalent (kindof), so this works!

Comment: That worked *perfectly*. Thank-you so much. I don't suppose you could explain what this does: `...map(&:article)`?