# Simple recursive method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Board model. Board can be subscribed to other boards (as a feed).
Lets say I have board tree like this:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f7/Binary_tree.svg/200px-Binary_tree.svg.png

So:
`Board.find(2).feeds` are boards 5 and 7
`Board.find(7).feeds` are boards 2 and 6 etc.

I want to write method `all_feeds` which returns all feeds from all levels for certain board. For example:
`Board.find(7).all_feeds` would output array of boards with ids: 2,6,5,11

I started with something like:

```
  def all_feeds
    if feeds.empty?
      return
    else
      feeds.each {|feed| feed.all_feeds}
      return feeds
    end
  end
```

Probably have to add this return feeds to some global array, but not sure how should I do this.

Thanks for help.

ps. this is not always a binary tree, you can have more than 2 feeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that what you want could be achieved with:

```
def all_feeds
  unless feeds.empty?
    feeds + feeds.map(&:all_feeds).flatten.compact
  end
end
```

[Array#flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) makes the result one-dimensional, while [Array#compact](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact) removes the nil components.

For an explanation of the `map(&:all_feeds)` part, you can refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269052/rails-build-for-difference-between-relationships/17269714#17269714) :)

Comment: It doesn't work, I added new answer with code I think is working, have to test it.

Comment: oops, I guess I forgot to include the current level feeds before. See the updated answer!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's working for below code:

```
 def all_feeds
    if feeds.empty?
      self
    else
      [self]+feeds.map(&:all_feeds)
    end
  end
```

Comment: i guess you have recursion here with node id = 2, it will return itself tree each time you mapping `all_feeds` again and again inside itself

Comment: `all_feeds` should always return the same type. `[self] + feeds.map(&:all_feeds)` is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

if it is allowed to use gems [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem will help do the trick

```
Board.find(7).descendants
```

in this case it will be definitely one request to db without any recursion which is better for performance

you can implement ancestry idea without gem (or in top of it):

- add `ancestry` field to your model
- fill it correctly when you build your tree (for nested nodes with ids 2 and 6 it will be `2/7`, with ids 5 and 11 - `2/7/6` )
- and then just take it from db with `like 2/%` query